# Putting iframe inside an image

Tags: html, image, iframe

I have this box which looks like this:

[image]

I want to insert an iframe in the middle of the box in the circle which I got from timeanddate.com

I tried putting the iframe  after the image but it didn't work

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Is the image a white circle or a transparent circle?

Comment: is the image transparent ? i mean the white part ?

Comment: @rjustin yes it is

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes it is

Comment: @JoeF wait it can only be one

Comment: so if it's transparent the image can be above the iframe with some absolute/relative positon and z-index

Comment: just put the image over the top of the iframe

Comment: can you show us what you tried so far